# How can I allow a participant to enrol for an event more than once?

Tags: civievent, duplicate-contacts

At our nightshelter we have some volunteers that perform more than one role - e.g. as a van driver and also as kitchen staff.  To capture volunteer hours we sign volunteers in to the nightshelter event (using a webform), and would like to sign volunteers like these in twice - once for each role.  Using a matching rule in the webform that allows duplicates I hoped this would be possible, but only one signin is allowed. Is there a way to allow a participant to be signed in to an event twice, with different roles?  Using 4.7.24 with Drupal

Answer (score 1):

Do you already have multiple roles supported for your events?, i.e via an extension like: https://civicrm.org/extensions/event-registration-based-participant-roles

A solution that would not necessarily be graceful would be to create multiple events (one for each role) and use the form to hit the different events based on the role.

Comment: As I'm using a webform to sign people in the role can be chosen at signin, so that's not the problem that this extension overcomes.  The issue is trying to sign the same person in twice with different roles each signin.  But thanks for the suggestion!  Andy